# PythonAPI Request

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

````
Source=["SGD"]
Destination=["USD"]
Amount=[5000]

```import requests
   url = "https://api.currencyfair.com/comparisonQuotes"
   payload = "{\"currencyFrom\":\"SGD\",\"currencyTo\":\"EUR\",\"type\":\"SELL\",\"amountInfo\": 
  {\"amount\":50000,\"scale\":2}}"
  headers = {
    'user-agent': "vscode-restclient",
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'accept': "application/json"
    }
   response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
   print(response.text)
````

I need to pass values to payload string -
payload = "{"currencyFrom":"**SGD**","currencyTo":"**EUR**","type":"SELL","amountInfo":{"amount":**50000**,"scale":2}}"
Need to pass values to payload using 3 list created above```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to explain a bit more what you're after?

I suspect what you mean is that you'd like to dynamically update the values in the text **payload** every time you call the function to post data.

I'd usually go about doing this by creating a placeholder string then updating that by replacing placeholder values at runtime.

```
payload = "{\"currencyFrom\":\"@currencyFrom\",\"currencyTo\":\"@currencyTo\",\"type\":\"SELL\",\"amountInfo\": {\"amount\":@amountInfo,\"scale\":2}}"

currencyFrom = 'USD'
currencyTo = 'EUR'
amountInfo = 50000

payload = payload.replace('@currencyFrom', currencyFrom).replace('@currencyTo', currencyTo).replace('@amountInfo', amountInfo)
```

Looking at the API you're trying to interact with, this is a sample of what it expects:

```
{"currencyFrom": "EUR",
"currencyTo": "GBP",
"type": "SELL",
"amountInfo": {"amount": 100},
"ignoreFee": false}
```

This is a JSON object that follows a specific format, if you try and pass a list as opposed to a string in the "currencyFrom", "currencyTo" fields etc you'll get an error.

To get multiple values as responses simply conduct multiple requests to the API, for example:

```
payload = "{\"currencyFrom\":\"@currencyFrom\",\"currencyTo\":\"@currencyTo\",\"type\":\"SELL\",\"amountInfo\": {\"amount\":@amountInfo,\"scale\":2}}"

currencyFrom = ['USD', 'GBP']
currencyTo = ['EUR', 'CHF']
amountInfo = 50000

payload = payload.replace('@currencyFrom', currencyFrom).replace('@currencyTo', currencyTo).replace('@amountInfo', amountInfo)
for currFrom in currencyFrom:
    for currTo in currencyTo:
        for amount in amountInfo:
            payload = payload.replace('@currencyFrom', currFrom ).replace('@currencyTo', currTo ).replace('@amountInfo', amount )
            response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Hope this makes sense!

Edit: Updating code as per your comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying :)
I mean that in Source, Destination, Amount variables, I would have multiple values and I would need to pass those values to payload  - 3 highlighted values in payload would be passed through 3 list variables..

Comment: Let say, I have two values in Destination=["USD","AUD"] and i would like to pass those to payload in place of "EUR"

Comment: I've updated the code above to better illustrate how you can get where you want. I'd also encourage you to have a quick read on how APIs work and pass around JSON objects. You don't need the payload in a string format, converting it into a JSON object would make everything easier and your code cleaner!

Comment: Thanks, When I run above code, I get
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not list
The error is thrown on payload - payload = payload.replace('@currencyFrom', currencyFrom).replace('@currencyTo', currencyTo).replace('@amountInfo', amountInfo)
Please help